# When creating a view how to include the namespace and schemabinding?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How  would you include SCHEMABINDING Along with the XMLNAMESPACES

```
CREATE View [dbo].[GetSomething] As

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://www.something.com/some.xsd' AS gev)

-- How to include SCHEMABINDING--

SELECT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Something WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 

WITH XMLNAMESPACES
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE View [dbo].[GetSomething] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://www.something.com/some.xsd' AS gev)

SELECT -- Make sure your select follows the rules for schemabinding of course
```